# How to find common elements from multiple vectors and from a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

Could anyone please tell me how to find out the common elements from a multiple vectors and with each row element of the matrix in R?

```
a <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
b <- c(3,6,8,9,10)
c <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

So, that I can find the intersect between

```
intersect(intersect(a,b),c[[1]]) for row1 of the C matrix
intersect(intersect(a,b),c[[2]]) for row2 of the C matrix
```

and so on for all the other rows with a for loop..

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything in this post to disapprove..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
 Map(intersect, split(c, row(c)), list(intersect(a,b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(c,1,function(x){
intersect(intersect(a,b),x)
})
```

Comment: Is the argument of the function declared in apply